# How do I get Python controls into the toolbox in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I want to create a WinForms IronPython app.

I have installed IronPython, but the toolbox is empty.

How to I add Python controls to it?

Answer (score 1):

The toolbox is only available if you create an IronPython WPF Application. Unfortunately there is no designer support for a IronPython Windows Form Applications. The Windows Form has to be completely written in Python.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Projects#project-types. (Read the "IronPython Windows Forms Application" section)